# how to add strings in an array of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays. Say an array of fruits, and each fruit array has an array of properties.
Something like

```
[["Apple", "seedless", "red"],["Banana", "seedless", "yellow"]]
```

I now have another array which has an additional property of each of the fruits in the same order as the fruits. say my other array is ["sour","sweet"]. The sour property is to be added to the apple array of properties and sweet is to be added to the banana array of properties so the resultant array looks like

```
[["Apple", "seedless", "red", "sour"],["Banana", "seedless", "yellow", "sweet"]]
```

How do I get to the inner array and append it?
I know in the inner array I just have to do

```
for(var i=0; i<tastePropArray.length; i++){
innerArray.push(tastePropArray(i));
}
```

but How do I reach/access that inner array?

Comment: Try nested loop accessors `outerArray[i][j]` or just use objects, which would seem to be more suited to what you need.

Comment: Using array objects would be better in this case I suppose..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fruits = [["Apple", "seedless", "red"],["Banana", "seedless", "yellow"]];
for(var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++){
    fruits[i].push(tastePropArray[i]);
}
```

But I will propose a better datamodel:

Store your fruits like:

```
var fruits = {
    "Apple": {
         "seeds": "no",
         "colour": "red",
         "taste": "sour"
    },
    "Banana": {
         "seeds": "no",
         "colour": "yellow",
         "taste": "sweet"
    }
};

console.log(fruits.Apple.taste); // sour
```

Add fruits like:

```
fruits.StrawBerry = {
    "seeds": "yes",
    "colour": "red",
    "taste": "sweet"
}
```

Use a `for .. in` to loop over the fruits.

Comment: I like your first answer, that is most relevant for me. However thanks a lot, more knowledge about programming never hurts !

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [["123","234"],["asd","fff"]]

a[0] // prints ["123", "234"]
a[0][0] // prints "123"
```

Sorry i misunderstood the question @Frits van Campen answer is absolutely right.